# Bookmark directories?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

In Ubuntu Nautilus, I can bookmark directories that I frequent. Even when the directories are moved elsewhere, their bookmarks can change automatically. I was wondering if the bookmarks are implemented as hard links or soft links?

In Windows 7, is there similar function as bookmarking directories for Windows Explorer?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: You cannot hardlink directories on Unix, and symlinks are incapable of updating automatically (they point to a textual path). (Do not forget that Nautilus' bookmarks can point to any location supported by GVFS, not necessarily on the local filesystem.) It's more likely that there's some sort of watcher process that acts when a bookmarked place is moved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can, this is what the **favourites** feature in the left pane is for.

When you are in a directory you want to favourite, right-click **favourites** and hit **add current directory to favourites**.

[image]

In Ubuntu these are likely done with soft links or inode numbers, as hard links can't traverse file system boundaries.

Comment: Thanks! Is it that if the file being linked to is moved, the soft link will not work? In Ubuntu Nautilus, the bookmark can still point to the correct file after the file is moved elsewhere.

Comment: If it still works after the file location is changed, it is probably using inode #'s.

Comment: Do not forget that Nautilus' bookmarks can point to any location supported by GVFS, not necessarily on the local filesystem. (Including, but is limited to, SFTP, FTP, CIFS, WebDAV and OBEX.) Not all of them have inode numbers. Heck, not even _local_ filesystems always have inode numbers... Just saying.